# Prove $n \mu(|f| \geq n) \to 0$ for any integrable $f$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f$ be integrable; 
>   $$\int |f| d\mu < \infty$$
>   Prove that:
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \mu (E_n)= 0$$
>   where
>   $$E_n = \{x: |f(x)| \ge n \}$$

Intuitively it is quite obvious. I don't know how to write a formal proof however.
I tried to create a sequence of functions $f_n$ which would be increasing and then use one of Lebesgue's theorems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$n \mu(E_n) = \int_{|f(x)| \geq n} n \, \mu(dx) \leq \int_{|f(x)| \geq n} |f(x)| \, \mu(dx).$$

Comment: What does $\mu (dx)$ mean?

Comment: @Hendrra Integration with respect to the measure $\mu$... replace it my $d\mu(x)$ if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks! So now, after adding limits I get the thesis?

Comment: @Hendrra Well, that's what my hint is suggesting... What theorem do you apply to derive the assertion?

Comment: I think two Lebesgue's theorems can be used here. The sequence is growing. Moreover it is bounded.

Comment: @Hendrra Which sequence is growing...? If it was growing, then it could hardly converge to $0$, right?